# How to separate Onboard soundcard sound from USB Headphones

Tags: usb, audio, sound-card, speakers, headphones

I would like to use my onboard soundcard (Realtek) to play music out of for my wife on the speakers,
While I use my USB headphones to listen to and play a video game.
I know it's possible as I've done it before, but I can't figure out what I did to get it to work.

I thought before I would pick my speakers as Default audio device, start up music/movie then change my default device to Headphones and then start up game, all the while the music/movie would stay on speakers and anything I started up after changing headphones to default would play out of headphones.

I'm running Windows 7 x64.
I do also have a separate sound card installed just incase that would help/work. But guessing it doesn't matter much since they are USB headphones.

So, who can tell me what I did before to get 2 separate audios playing out of speakers and headphones simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the *default* audio device to play music through your speakers, you do not change it again.

What you need to do is change the *application specific* audio device, in the application's own settings, so that it plays through the USB headphones.  You need to look into your game's audio settings.

Comment: I don't know many if any games that allow you to change which audio device the audio plays through.

And I'm pretty positive that last time I did get it to work I would play something out of speakers (which is always default) and then I would change the default to headphones and play my game. But for some reason it's not working now.

How do you change which sound device/card to use as default for games? I've never seen that option in a video game before.

Comment: @user391559 The way you think worked for you before certainly did not work the way you describe.  The only way for to select a different audio device is within the application itself.  There are games and apps that allow this, but not all.

Comment: I know you say it's not possible, but I know I did it before that way somehow. I never changed anything in any application or game, I know I did it through the sound playback menu.
If you don't know how that's fine.

Comment: @user391559 I think the only way it could have worked that was was through a bug of some sort.

Comment: yeah it might've been. Maybe that's why I can't get it to work. But I'm positive that's how I did it. I know I never changed anything in any application or game. 

I remember it took me a few days of searching around and trying all kinds of things, but I eventually got it to work.

I just remember that I'd start music/movie for wife/kids and then I'd change default audio device and it would keep audio of music/movie on speakers and then anything I started up afterwards would play in headphones.